# UDP Server not receiving from Xamarin.iOS UDP client

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, xamarin, udp

I am trying to send an UDP datagram from a client in xamarin.iOS via UDP. These are the following Receive/Send client-side functions:

```
public int Send(byte[] data)
{
    if (_socket == null)
    {
        try
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
                Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? SocketOptionName.PacketInformation : SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress,
                true
                );

            OpenUDPSocket(data);
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); return 0; }
    }
    try
    {
        //Console.WriteLine($"[UDP] He intentado mandar por UDP.");
        return _socket.SendTo(data, SocketFlags.None, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverAddress), serverPortUDP));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); return 0; }
}
```

Trying to test the datagram sended by a LabView UDP server demo, it works fine, it receives correctly the following datagram:

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            byte[] data1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("UDPtestdatagram");
            OpenUDPSocket(data1);
        }
    });
```

Now, this is de following code from my C# UDP server:

```
public Server(string ip, int port)
{
    // Fill Server variables
    _ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    _client = new UdpClient(port);
   
    // Listen to incoming clients
    StartMessageLoop();

    // Keep running the Server
    bool keepRunning = true;
    while (keepRunning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'quit' to exit the application.");
        string? input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input != null && input == "quit")
        {
            keepRunning = false;
        }
    }

    // Perform any necessary cleanup here
    Console.WriteLine("Exiting the application...");
}

public void StartMessageLoop()
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            int length = _client.Receive(receivedData, ref _ep);

            // Retrieve the sender and the destination's NumLockgene
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(async () => {
                    string frame = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(receivedData);
                    Console.WriteLine($"RCV");
                    (int senderNL, int receiverNL) = await ParseFrame(frame);
                
                    if (senderNL != -1 && receiverNL != -1)
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine($"Sender: {senderNL}, Receiver: {receiverNL}");

                        LocalUser? existingUser = localUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.GetNL() == senderNL);
                        if (existingUser != null)
                        {
                            existingUser.SetClient(_ep);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LocalUser newUser = new LocalUser(_ep, senderNL);
                            localUsers.Add(newUser);
                        }

                        foreach (LocalUser user in localUsers)
                        {
                            if (user.GetNL() == receiverNL)
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine($"[Send to {receiverNL}]");
                                byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(frame);
                                await SendTo(user.GetClient(), data);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The thing is, the server is correctly receiving UDP datagrams either from Android client or whatever TCP/UDP app of iOS App Store. But it is not receiving from our client Xamarin.iOS application (if you run the same app in Android works fine).
It is important to remark that our iOS Xamarin application is sending correctly the UDP datagram to the LabView UDP demo server, so I do not have any idea why is C# UDP server not receiving that UDP datagram.

Why is my C# server not receiving from that iOS xamarin app UDP Client?

Comment: There is not route between the client and server.  Testing with PING usually help identify the issue.  The IOS is on a private network and not on same network as the client.  Sometimes the issue is the port number is blocked by a firewall or the port number is already being used.  Also you may be using IPV6 instead of IPV4.  See : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-tcpip-settings-on-mac-mh14129/mac?force_isolation=true

Comment: I solved it deleting "_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
                Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? SocketOptionName.PacketInformation : SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress,
                true
                );" I could say that ReuseAddress is not the propper way to do the UDP socket? I do not know. The simplier the better I guess.

Comment: Hi Raul, your comment deserves an answer. You could post an answer below. That may help others with same issues.